# split an email list by delimiter returns more than expected number of rows

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have the following schema and SQL script: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9c7bb/9

```
create table a(
 cond varchar2(400),
 email varchar2(400) 
);
insert into a values('CPU_consumption', 'name_1@email.com;name_2@email.com;name_3@email.com');
insert into a values('number of processes', 'name_1@email.com');
insert into a values('memory consumption', 'name_1@email.com;name_2@email.com;');

SELECT 
 regexp_substr(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)',1,level,NULL,1) AS result
FROM a
WHERE cond = 'memory consumption'
CONNECT BY level < regexp_count(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)');
```

Result:

```
name_2@email.com
name_2@email.com
name_1@email.com
name_2@email.com
```

Can anyone explain why the result is not only 2 rows with the email addresses?
Why there is displayed the 2nd email; address twice and after that the required list?

Comment: Can you add the code to the question instead of the link only?

Comment: Your question is basically "I used `connect by`, what does it do?" and I have a funny feeling that this has been answered countless times on this site and on the internet in general.

Comment: Connect by level kinda sucks. One would assume it uses the result after the WHERE, but somehow connects to those filtered out...  I've played around with this, and if your version (> 12c) supports [OUTER APPLY](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1) then it's usable.  A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1028a898fcce9a8622dec36fb1fb92f)*

Answer (score 1):

Because `connect by` mixed `memory consumption` with other values. You can check it if you add path and root in your query:

```
select level, regexp_substr(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as result, 
       connect_by_root(cond) root, sys_connect_by_path(cond, ' -> ') path
  from a 
  where cond = 'memory consumption' 
  connect by level < regexp_count(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)');
```

You should start with proper value and check it in next steps:

```
select level, regexp_substr(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)', 1, level, null, 1) as result
  from a 
  connect by level < regexp_count(email,'((.*?)*?)(;|$)') and cond = 'memory consumption'
  start with cond = 'memory consumption';
```

<sup>**[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff3d3/1)**</sup>